# Loading .xls file with macros using PowerShell Core for Mac

Tags: comobject, powershell-core, new-object

I am trying to load an Excel file using PowerShell Core for Mac but I am encountering an issue with `New-Object`. It's failing on the very first line

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
```

This is the error message I receive:

```
New-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
'ComObject'.
At line:1 char:21
+ $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Has anyone encountered this issue and does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: The `Excel.Application` COM object is only available when Excel is installed. And I'm not sure if the Mac version of MS Office even provides COM objects. You may want to consider using the [`ImportExcel`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel) PowerShell module instead.

Comment: There is not ComObject in Mac OSX even when Excel for Mac is installed.

Answer (score 4):

The error message you're receiving says the `-ComObject` parameter is invalid. Judging from [this issue posted on the powershell github](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4897) I'd say `-ComObject` is invalid because it is not supported on the Mac platform.